# Flask can't see sqlite db when launched via uWSGI Emperor

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, uwsgi

When I run my Flask app via uWSGI emperor, it 502's out with a Sqlite error regarding it not being able to see my tables. I can go in via the sqlite3 command and verify the data is there. When I run the site via

```
uwsgi --ini site_conf.ini
```

it works just fine, but not via emperer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are not using relative paths when referring to the sqlite db. When run by the Emperor the cwd changes to the vassals dir. Eventually use chdir option in your vassal to move to a specific directory